# getIntent().getStringExtra() eventually returning null

Tags: android, android-intent

So in Activity A I pass some data to activity B through an intent. Ok, everything is fine and `getStringExtra` returns what I expect. Then from activity B, I pass the same data to activity C. Then, when I hit the back button in the toolbar (because of `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`), the `getStringExtra` in activity B is now `null`.

So the flow is A (passes a string)-> B(passes the same string) -> C (back button in toolbar) -> B and now the variable passes from A to B is `null`. How can I fix that?

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Are you sending the same intent or puting the string value to a new intent before sending it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark this a rule : Whenever you are using the toolbar back button, you should take care of specifying the `launchMode` of the parent activity.

In your case, what happens after you press back button in Activity C, depends on what [launchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) have you specified for your activity B.

If you have't specified any launch mode, the default launch mode is `standard`. In this case,  the parent activity (B) is popped off the stack, and a new instance of that activity is created on top of the stack to receive the intent.

If you have specified launch mode as `singleTop`, the parent activity is brought to the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its onNewIntent() method. That is, the previous activity is preserved.

Refer http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp.

In your case, you want to preserve the variable, therefore you should use `singleTop` launchMode.

Comment: no problem . Just make sure you always read the docs when implementing a new feature :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are extracting the data in onCreate method of Activity B then when you hit the back button in Activity C, the onCreate method of Activity B is not called again. To get more clarity on the life cycle of an Activity I really suggest you go through this developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Coming to your question when you start Activity B from Activity A, store the string that you sent from A to B in a global variable rather than a local one, and perform check like

```
public Class B extends Activity {
private String stringData;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xml_layout);
        if(getIntent().hasExtra(yourKeyName)) {
            stringData = getIntent().getStringExtra(yourKeyName);
        }
        //Do other stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think storing in a global variable is a good idea. The thing is, he wants to preserve the instance of activity B so that all variables are preserved. Tomorrow if some other variable comes like this, then again he'll have to store globally.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity B, always check before getting the String -

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_NAME))
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_NAME);
```

Reason being that when you press the back button then Activity B is not launched with the same intent that you create in Activity A. Hence the extras are not present.

Comment: But how do I still avoid it being null? The check works but I need s to always be something from the intent from A.

Comment: It will always contain something if its launched from A. Once you extract this String in Activity B, assign it to a global variable in Activity B itself. Then we you re-enter Activity B by pressing the back button on Activity C, your intent extra will be null but your String will be present in that global variable that you assigned it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should be string the string extra as a global variable and always use a hasExtra check.

Comment: I don't think storing in a global variable is a good idea. The thing is, he wants to preserve the instance of activity B so that all variables are preserved. Tomorrow if some other variable comes like this, then again he'll have to store globally.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is different processes.

- The first one, when you start activity B from activity A, you pass
  the data from activity A to activity B. It is obvious, so the data
  will be present.
- The second one, then you start activity C from activity B, because of
  activity B is not on the foreground, then your data will be erased.

You can persist your data on activity B by many ways.

- One of them you can implement a static global variable.
- Second way, you can save your variables on activity B by saving the
  data onSaveInstanceState and retrieve from onRestoreInstanceState or
  onCreate
- Third way you can listen onActivityResult on activity B from activity
  C. When you starting activity C, you must use startActivityOnResult
  and passing the data that you want to pass back on activity B. After
  you finish your activity C, you must return the data that originally
  from activity B.

And so on...

But the better way to achieve that is the second way, use bundle onSaveInstanceState and retrieve the bundle data when onCreate.

Comment: refer to this link about onSaveInstanceState http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html